# Union of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In Axler's book *Linear Algebra Done Right*, there is an exercise:

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $F$ where $\# F>2$, then the union of three subspaces of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ iff one of the subspaces contains the other two.

I can do this exercise by myself, and I am trying to prove the generalization of this statement, but I have been stuck on it.

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $F$ where $\# F>n-1$, then the union of n subspaces of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ iff one of the subspaces contains the others.

Edit: Here's my proof for the case $n=3$. Also, I want to prove this theorem using only concepts of vector spaces and subspaces.

> *Proof.* Assume the contrary. Suppose $U_1, U_2, U_3$, and $U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3$ are subspaces of $V$, but none of the $U_i$s contains the other. WLOG, we may assume that $U_i\not\subseteq U_j$ for $i\neq j$, or it reduces to the case $n=2$.
>
> Consider $u=a+kb$, where $a\in U_1\setminus U_2\cup U_3, b\in U_2\setminus U_1\cup U_3$, and $k\neq0,1$.
> It's obvious that $k\notin U_1$ and $k\notin U_2$, so $k\in U_3$.
> Now, consider $v=a+(k-1)b,$ $v$ must in $U_3$. But this implies that $v-u=b\in U_3$, a contradiction.

But I don't know how to apply my method on a larger $n$.

Edit 2: Here's the proof :)

> *Proof.* Assume the contrary. Suppose $U_1, U_2, \dots, U_n$, and $U_1\cup U_2\cup \dots \cup U_n$ are subspaces of $V$, but none of the $U_i$s contains the other. WLOG, we may assume that $U_i\not\subseteq U_j$ for $i\neq j$, or it reduces to the case of $n-1$ subspaces.
>
> Consider $U=\{a+kb\mid k\in F\setminus\{0\}\}$, where $a\in U_1\setminus U_2\cup U_3 \cup \dots \cup U_n$ and $b\in U_2\setminus U_1\cup U_3 \cup U_4 \cup \dots \cup U_n$.
> Then for every $u\in U$, $u\not\in U_1$ and $u\not\in U_2$.
>
> Since $\# U = \# F - 1 > n - 2$, by the pigeon hole principle, there exists distinct $u_1, u_2\in U$
> such that $u_1, u_2\in U_j$ for some $j\neq 1,2$. Write $u_1=a+k_1b$
> and $u_2=a+k_2 b$, then we have $u_1-u_2=(k_1-k_2)b\in U_j$, a
> contradiction!

Comment: Maybe there is a clue in how you did the $n=3$ case?

Comment: I have a proof in the case where $F$ is infinite, maybe we can adapt it to finite $F$..

Comment: @Lelouch Can I see your proof? It might give me some ideas to prove the case where $F$ is finite.